# GetVersionInfoSizeEx() failing on a DLL, but not on a copy of the same

Tags: winapi, .net-core, reverse-engineering

Occasionally when deploying my app* a seemingly random one of the bundled DLLs gets in a strange state. On the instance I'm debugging now it's System.Net.Security.dll (from .NET Core 3.1), but it could be any.

- In Explorer, the DLL shows no version information (version, product name, copyright, etc).
- The .NET app fails to load the library, yielding a BadImageFormatException: assembly manifest not found.
- Resource Hacker **does** show the version info block.
- When I make a copy of the DLL, the copy works fine. The original and copy are bit-for-bit identical.
- When I make a disk image of the disk and attach it elsewhere, the problematic file is fine.
- When I call *GetVersionInfoSizeEx()* on the DLL, it fails with error 1813 (`ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`). It works fine on the bit-for-bit identical copy.

[image: Screenshot]

Since there clearly is nothing wrong with the bits in the file, I'm inclined to suspect corruption in sort of cache or in-memory data structure.

**How come the version info cannot be read for this DLL, while it can be read just fine from an identical copy?**

---

I did some digging and found that the resource APIs call *LoadLibraryEx()* with `LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE | LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE`. After some hoops we end up in ntdll's private *LdrpResGetResourceDirectory()* which does some calculations and looks up a field at an offset inside the module:

```
00007ffd`c4c17f61 0fb74a0e        movzx   ecx,word ptr [rdx+0Eh]
00007ffd`c4c17f80 6685c9          test    cx,cx
00007ffd`c4c17f83 7463            je      ntdll!LdrpResGetResourceDirectory+0x408 (00007ffd`c4c17fe8)
```

`rdx` is a pointer to somewhere inside the module. From my reading:

```
rdx = handle + 0x100 + somestruct.(0x14) - somestruct.(0x0C)
```

This is where the execution diverges between the problematic original DLL and the bit-for-bit identical copy: `cx` is 0 for the bad original but 1 for the good copy.

(I've tried calling *LoadLibrary()* on the DLL and then dumping the memory to compare it against the original DLL, but I can't make out the forest for the trees in the resulting diff.)

---

*) A self-contained .NET Core 3.1 application that's deployed to Windows Server 2019 Azure Batch nodes by way of downloading and extracting a zip, then robocopying it to shared/.

Comment: A quick debug tells me that `rdx` is pointing to the [`IMAGE_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/d43/pedump_8c_source.html#l00382) of the PE file, thus +0x0e is pointing on the `NumberOfIdEntries` field (confirmed by setting a BP on the function and looking at the pointer). I'm still puzzled as to why in your case, for two identical copies, it's different.

Comment: Thanks @Neitsa. Windbg (classic) didn't show me this info, maybe I need to set up symbol servers or such.

Comment: look for flags in call - *Loads the version resource strings from the **corresponding MUI file**, if available* - so actually try load from another file (MUI) (located by name)

Comment: Already checked that, @RbMm, it occurs with all combinations of the `FILE_VER_*` flags (and succeeds on the copy, with all combinations). Also occurs when the filenames are swapped.

Comment: so really it looked in mui file, not in dll. this is explain why on copy (with **another name** ) is ok

Comment: I see that point, but when I rename the original to System.Net.Security-orig.dll and the copy to System.Net.Security.dll, it still fails on -orig and works with the (now named after the original) copy.

Comment: interesting, but need look under debugger on system where this

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to reproduce this outside of the Azure Batch environment, so far I can only repro it by spinning up a bunch of nodes and hoping one fails.

Comment: will be more easy, if look on call tree and compare (fail and ok tree) - like this - https://i.imgur.com/FncBpHF.png

Comment: Can do. What tool is this? I'm using Windbg (classic, no Store on this one) but I've never used it before.

Comment: for debug this need remote access to machine, where this error :)

Comment: Ah yes that's another issue, it's behind an Azure Batch access gateway. Hence trying to reproduce it elsewhere.